# Input validation working in web but not in Android/iOS Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In my Searchbar i have implemented pattern validation .

So basically i want to restrict users to enter numeric and some special characters in search bar.
Html File

```
<ion-searchbar animated searchIcon=undefined clearIcon=undefined 
  [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"
  (ionFocus)="focusInput($event)" 
  (ionChange)="filteredItems()" 
  placeholder="Search for product" 
  (keypress)="validateProductSearch($event)" 
  (ionInput)="validateProductSearch($event)" 
  (keyup)="validateProductSearch($event)" >
 </ion-searchbar>
```

ts file-

```
validateProductSearch(event: any) {
    const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z\_\-',.:`"() ]*$/
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

This is working in web browser. but when i am installing apk in phone/tablet this validation is not working.
I have tried IonInput, Keyup, and Key press.

user is able to enter anything.

using ionic 5 version.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Change *keypress* to *ionInput* as stated into the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar)